# Exception is thrown when debugger is attached but it is not thrown when the program started without debugging

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I'm programming an interface. I use a DLL which uses a network socket. The program throws a SocketException when I unplug the ethernet cable and then plug it back*, if the debugger is attached. The exception is not thrown when program is started without debugging, and it continues to work just fine.

What may be the cause of this ?

*My application is running on a virtual machine, the vm is bridged to my local network. My computer is connected internet via wifi. When I unplug ethernet cable, the vm changes the network connection to wifi without raising any network availability changed event. When I plug it back, the exception is thrown if the debugger attached, and it is not thrown if the debugger is not attached.

Comment: It may be that you have some code in debug mode which is allowing it not to crash the application .. In short please check the code which is executing in the debug mode / which is executing in the normal mode

Comment: Is the exception actually handled by the application?  The debugger may be set up to pause on all exceptions, even ones that are ultimately handled.

Comment: If you have a short re-create then post it here. Otherwise you need to learn how to add enough logging to diagnose your issue without an attached debugger. But without a lot more detail: code, error messages, re-creation steps, there is not enough here to work with.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. After checking the code, and the debugger configurations, I have realized debugger configuration is set to throw SocketExceptions always. Reconfiguring the debugger worked. Interestingly, while I'm handling the exception, I log the exception details in a txt file. But when I checked the txt file, there is no trace of that exception. Anyways, I'm going to search solutions for not logging problem, if I can not find a solution I will ask it in another question. Thanks again.